# If interference occurs in single slit, why don't we see interference when we drop a pebble in still water?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, waves

I am confused about the above question. I know why interference through single slit happens due to Hyugen's Principle. But, is we see interference with a single wave also, why don't we see such things in real life as well. Like if I drop a pebble in a perfectly still water, I see a nice circular wave forming. I don't see any interference pattern forming at all. So in the same token then when a single wave comes out from one slit, why does it form interference pattern?

Comment: Can you comment on why it is hard to visualize? I had a theory like, because there are infinite number of points on wave that is producing wavelets, all the wavlets overlap/interfere with each other to a point where there is constructive interference on every single point, and thus this is the reason we don't see patches of dark and bright spot. However, then why I am wondering why don't we see such a thing also happening with waves passing through single slit?

Comment: http://waiferx.blogspot.co.il/2013/01/presentation-diffraction.html. The second image on this blog is a good picture of single-slit water wave pattern. But how to measure the intensity?

Comment: Here you go from MIT: https://youtu.be/egRFqSKFmWQ

Answer (score 2):

> why don't we see such things in real life as well

We do. You don't see it if you just drop a pebble in water because that situation just looks like a point source. If you actually do the analog of the single slit experiment, that is, if you look at a plane wave of water incident on a single slit, you will see an interference pattern. You can see an example of water waves in this example by ben crowell [here](https://phys.libretexts.org/TextMaps/Introductory_Physics_Textmaps/Map%3A_Conceptual_Physics_(Crowell)/12%3A_Optics/12.5_Wave_Optics). The image itself is [image]

Comment: Your second link is broken on my device. If it's an image, to prevent pink rot, it's best to load it into stack.imgur as usual.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Thanks. I am/was on my phone. I will check it out later.